# email picture with animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, email, animation, image

In my application I use `MFMailComposeViewController` to send an email.

I add a picture with this code :

```
NSURL *aUrl  = [NSURL URLWithString:photoURL];
NSData   *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:aUrl];

[self addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:siteName];
```

The modal view is fine, and the picture is there.

My question is : Is it possible to do the same annimation that we could see when we send by email a picutre from the photo app? Where the picture fly and the mail composer modal view appear under the picture?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be probably accessible using one of Apple's private APIs, which will get your app rejected from the App Store.

Please, check the first important note in the official [MFMailComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMailComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) class reference.

> The mail composition interface itself is not customizable and must not be modified by your application.